# Aが ...しないでほしい or Aに ...しないでほしい?

Tags: grammar

> 遊「いい先輩だけど！俺にとってはちょっとやっかいな先輩なの！」
>
> 子供の頃、無理矢理、乱取り稽古に付き合わされたし。
>
> 本人は『あんたをもっと強くしてやる』という善意だったらしいが。
>
> そもそも合気道の達人**が**、一般人と8時間も組み手をしないでほしい。

Hi. I was taught to use the construction 「Aに ...しないでほしい」. So why is the bold part が instead of に?
Doesn’t it mean “I don’t want the 達人 to practice 合気道 with ordinary people for 8 hours”?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very interesting question and I don't have a clear answer, but I'm wondering if this is related to the "derogatory vocative-like が" explained in [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72072/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76418/5010).

This が is used only when the speaker has a negative feeling about the person. For example, you **cannot** replace に with が in the following examples (at least, not with the same meaning):

- 彼**に**この本を読んで欲しい。
- 彼**に**この本を読まないで欲しい。
  <sup>(EDIT: Apparently this is not as common as I had initially perceived; see the comments and Kay's answer)</sup>
- 彼**に**この本を読んで欲しくない。

However, somehow we **can** say the following:

- 彼のような人間**が**この本を読まないで欲しい。
- 彼のような人間**が**この本を読んで欲しくない。
- 馬鹿**が**この本を読まないで欲しい。
- 馬鹿**が**この本を読んで欲しくない。

And the only reason I can think of is that 彼のような人間 and 馬鹿 are negative/derogatory phrases. Of course 合気道の達人 is basically positive, but here it has a negative implication, "an inappropriate person to train a child".

Unfortunately I don't know how this can be generalized further...

Comment: 肯定形の時も卑下法にとれますかね？「もう、あなたがやってほしい」みたいな

Comment: @user4092 それや「彼がこの本を読んでほしい」は単なるexaustive-gaのような気がします。でも「お前が言うな」はexhaustive-gaではなくこの用法かもしれません。ややこしい…。

Comment: 確かに質問者さんの文に出てくる「が」はこの解釈の方が正しいように思います。 なお、narutoさんの回答として明言されていなかったですが「に」も使えるという答えでしょうか。。 とすれば、彼のような人間「に」この本を読まないでほしい。とも言えるということでしょうか。ただ、個人的には、文法的に間違ではないのかもしれませんが、とても違和感を感じてしまいます。彼のような人間に「読んでほしくない」は特に違和感ないのですが。文法的な議論でなくてすみませんが、ご意見伺えれば幸いです。

Comment: @Kay もちろん「が」を使わないといけないということはないと思います。個人的には、「彼のような人間にこの本を読まないでほしい」と「彼のような人間にこの本を読んでほしくない」はどちらも正しい自然な文のように思いますが、「に」の代わりに「には」を使う方がもう少し自然かもしれません（[この](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010)議論）。

Comment: @narutoさん　ありがとうございます。そうなのですね。。Aに～ないでほしい。（Aが主語）という文が使われている書籍や口語の資料が現代でいくつかあれば納得できるのですが、、、すみません。　やはり見覚え・聞き覚えがないせいで違和感を感じてしまいました。。

Comment: すみません。書き直します。目的語または副詞に付く「に」として、親に言わないでほしい。とか絶対に言わないでほしいとか、病気にならないでほしいとかは自然に感じますし、また私の回答本文に書いたように「～と言った」、「～と…」というのが付くなら、あまり言わないものの「Aに～しないでほしい」は不自然とまでは感じません。また、「には」や「にも」も…例えば「誰にも来ないでほしい」はやはり違和感があります。いくつか例文をGoogle検索しました。「彼に来ないでほしい」や「誰にも来ないでほしい」は2件、「彼に来てほしくない」が168,000件、「誰にも来てほしくない」は170,000件ありました。どうしても「ないでほしい」を使う場合は、「彼のような人に～させないでほしい。」というと思います。何故ならこれは「あなた」に対して言っているから自然なのだと思います。「Aに～しないでほしい」（Aは「あなた」を除く主語）は「生きている言葉」なのだろうか…と感じてしまいました。。そうした言葉にあまり出会ったことがないだけなのかもしれませんが、、釈然としないコメントですみません。。私は文法的に正しいかどうかではなく実際に生きているかを伝えたいと思っているのですが、文法的にシビアに回答した方が良いのでしょうか…最近始めたのですが、悩ましく感じます。。

Comment: ＠Kay まず「絶対に言わないでほしい」「学校に行ってほしくない」とかの「に」は明らかに役目が違うので忘れましょう。あくまで誰かに何かをしてほしい/ほしくない時にその対象の人を指し示すための「に」に限って考えましょう。次に、Google検索のヒット数で文法構造の正確性を探るのは凄まじく不正確なのでこういう時はBCCWJなどの専用のコーパスを使う方がいいです。次に、その上で「～に～ないでほしい」のパターンをBCCWJで探したのですが、確かに「～に～してほしくない」と比べると自分が思っていたよりかなり稀でした。なのでKayさんの感じている違和感は正当なものだと思います。回答にも追記しました。ただ人によっては問題と感じないようなので、これはもう個人差なんですかね…。

Comment: @Kay あと念のためですが、辞書的な意味よりネイティブの直観の方が正しいことなんて幾らでもあるので、何が正しいか否かの判断で教条主義的になる必要はないと思います。むしろそれが出来るのがネイティブスピーカーの特権ですし。（今回のようにネイティブの直観がズレることも稀にはありますが…）

Comment: ありがとうございます。Google検索について失礼致しました。今後はBCCWJといったコーパスを活用致します。私もこんなに深く考えたことはなかったので、もし会話中や軽い読書で「彼にこの本を読まないで欲しい。」と見聞きしたら、違和感はあっても話が途切れるほどのものでもないので、あまり気にせず脳内で「読ませないで欲しい」か「読んで欲しくない」と自動的に変換して気にしない気がします。　今回は深く考えすぎてつい熱くなってしまって、意識するあまりというのもあるのかもしれません。。 　
またアドバイスありがとうございます。直感が当たることも多いとは思うのですが、稀とは言え反例が一つもないかといわれると、今回のようなこともあるのでそのあたりが難しいですね。。

Answer (score 1):

First, I think しないでほしい is usually not used with ～に in this situation though ”してほしくない” is often used with ～に.

In my opinion, しないでほしい is usually used solely. The object is "you", and it is usually omitted.

> そこに座らないでほしい。　I want you not to sit there.

Aに...しないでほしい can be used with "と言った", "と思った" and so on in a sentence like this:

> 私は彼にもうこれ以上罪を侵さないでほしいと言った。
> I said to him that I wanted him not to commit sin anymore.
> or
> I said to him "I want you not to commit sin anymore.".

Perhaps, Aに...しないでほしい you learned may be as below.

> 彼に迷惑行為をしないでほしい。　I want you not to do him anything he doesn't like.
> 彼女に近づくことはしないでしい。/彼女に近づかないでほしい。 I want you not to be close to her.

In this case, there are two object unlike the above two cases. One is "you" and the other is "someone/something".
It is the case we want "you" not to do something to "someone/something".

If you said

> そもそも合気道の達人**に**、一般人と8時間も組み手をしないでほしい。

I think this means...

> In the first place, I want you not to do Kumite against 達人 (cooperating) with ordinary people for 8 hours.

However, In my opinion, the correct meaning is

> In the first place, I want you not to do anything like that 達人 (like
> you) does sparring/Kumite with ordinary people (like me) for 8
> hours.”
> そもそも合気道の達人が一般人と8時間も組み手をするなんてこと、しないでほしい。

I think 遊 talks to 先輩 directly in his brain though she is not there.

By the way, there is another explanation like [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73128/can-a-verb-be-modified-too-many-times/73129#73129) or other answers.
Perhaps, I could be wrong, but I strongly feel it is weird to say/hear "AはBに～しないでほしい"... though it may be grammatically correct.

So, please note this is just my opinion as a Japanese.

Comment: でも日本語文法の説明などに「人にVないでほしい」"want 人 not to do" が載ってたり、ここでも「[AはBに〜しないでほしい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/73129/9831)」"A doesn't want B to 〜"、「[彼に来ないで欲しいですか？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/74574/9831)」"Do you want him not to come" などが出てきてるんですが。

Comment: As a Japanese, I strongly feel weird about "AはBに～しないでほしい" like ”神は人間に動物を食べることをしないでほしい”. I am not linguist and not majoring in modern literature, but I cannot stop feeling it is weird as a Japanese who lives now. However, perhaps, my answer could be grammatically wrong, so I changed my explanation.

Comment: @Chocolateさん、あくまで私の意見であり、正確な言語学的・文法的正解は私も言えません。ただ、質問者さんが例に上げた文章は現代のもの（おそらく漫画かラノベ）で、現代での”生きている”言葉に関していえば、 個人的には、あまりにも違和感のある言葉と感じます。 してほしくない。であればわかりますが、AはBに～しないでほしい。は、違和感しかありませんので、このように回答させて頂きました。

Comment: なお、貼って頂いたリンクにある「神は人間に動物を食べないでほしい」はやはり違和感を感じます。。文法的には間違いのではないのかもしれませんが。。。

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, が marks the subject that wants someone else to do something, just as you say.

- Aが Bに …してほしい：A wants B to do it

In practice, however, the form of してほしい itself often functions as a mood, rather than voice, that stands for the speaker's own desire. As a result, it's also used in the form where が marks the agent of the desired action.

- Aが …してほしい： I want A to do it / A should do it

As for the difference between normal に, the が version conveys a sense that you want or do not want **none other than that person** to do it. In that sense, we could think of it as a kind of exhaustive が.